# Is there a main process equivalent of ipcRender.invoke?

Tags: electron

[ipcRender.invoke()](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrendererinvokechannel-args) will allow a render process to get a promise from the main Electron process. But is there a reverse version – where the main process can call get a promise from a render window? Something like (pseudo code)…

```
win.webContents.invoke('preview-video', data).then((responseData) => {console.log(responseData)})
```

Comment: No, only ipcRenderer implements the `invoke()` function, ipcMain does not have anything like it currently. It only implements the `handle()` function which is the counterpart to `invoke` Is this a theoretical question or do you have a specific goal in mind?

Comment: I have also looked over the webContents docs - nothing like it is implemented there. Maybe it is worth a feature request.

Comment: Not theoretical. I need to open a series of videos in a render process and extract information from each one asynchronously. Right now I'm using [electron-promise-ipc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-promise-ipc), which works great. But I was wondering if maybe I'd missed a way of doing it natively. When I stumbled across `ipcRender.invoke()` I thought "Ooh! This is it!" and then I realized that it sends the data in the wrong direction. :-)